# What way I can attach a Excel file with this

Tags: shell

Here is the code I have given and the excel attachment what I receive in mail is corrupted

```
 #!/usr/bin/ksh
export MAILFROM="el@defiant.com" 
export MAILTO="youremail@gmail.com"
export SUBJECT="Test PDF for Email"
export BODY="/home/el/email_body.htm"
export ATTACH="/home/el/pdf-test.pdf"
export ATTACH1="/home/el/excel-test.xls"
export MAILPART=`uuidgen` ## Generates Unique ID
export MAILPART_BODY=`uuidgen` ## Generates Unique ID

(
 echo "From: $MAILFROM"
 echo "To: $MAILTO"
 echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
 echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
 echo "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$MAILPART\""
 echo ""
 echo "--$MAILPART"
 echo "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$MAILPART_BODY\""
 echo ""
 echo "--$MAILPART_BODY"
 echo "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 echo "You need to enable HTML option for email"
 echo "--$MAILPART_BODY"
 echo "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
 cat $BODY
 echo "--$MAILPART_BODY--"

 echo "--$MAILPART"
 echo 'Content-Type: application/pdf; name="'$(basename $ATTACH)'"'
 echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: uuencode"
 echo 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'$(basename $ATTACH)'"'
 echo ""
 echo "--$MAILPART"
 echo 'Content-Type: application/msexcel; name="'$(basename $ATTACH1)'"'
 echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: Base-64"
 echo 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'$(basename $ATTACH1)'"'
 echo ""
 uuencode $ATTACH $(basename $ATTACH) && uuencode $ATTACH1 $(basename $ATTACH1)
 echo "--$MAILPART--"
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail $MAILTO
```

Please guide me on the content type and the content encoding type for excel because the data are corrupted once I get the file in mail.

Comment: echo "--$MAILPART"
 echo 'Content-Type: application/pdf; name="'$(basename $ATTACH)'"'
 echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: uuencode"
 echo 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'$(basename $ATTACH)'"'
 echo ""
 uuencode $ATTACH1 $(basename $ATTACH1)
 echo "--$MAILPART"
 echo 'Content-Type: application/msexcel; name="'$(basename $ATTACH1)'"'
 echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: Base-64"
 echo 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'$(basename $ATTACH1)'"'
 echo ""
 uuencode $ATTACH $(basename $ATTACH) 
 echo "--$MAILPART--"
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail $MAILTO

Comment: Please find the above solution.I got it.